# Unable to remove a PPA using the command: "ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu/ jammy main"

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                             
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease        
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

See Err:6 above. I tried to do a ppa-purge:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:shutter/ppa
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The target of your `ppa-purge` command is invalid.

The problematic PPA is `ppa:shutter/ppa`.

To remove it, use:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:shutter/ppa
```

Assuming there are no other issues, you can update your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I edited the body of the post to show what happens with the suggested ppa-purge.  I'm still looking for help with this as it is still not working.

Comment: There are a number of other ways to remove PPAs or sources.  Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/173199) or [remove them](https://askubuntu.com/a/173209) from your sources list by manually deleting or commenting the lines.  If none of these help, can you tell us how you added this PPA to begin with?

Comment: I was able to remove the ppa via ``` sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:shutter/ppa
``` at that point I could then update and upgrade my system.  Thank you Nmath